# Debugging Not working on VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2012, I have just create a windows application project, it's the default application created by VS itself, if I run the application with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> (Start Without Debugging), the application running correctly. while if I start the application with <kbd>F5</kbd> (Start With Debugging), The application is built successfully, but the form doesn't appear at all, In addition if I'm trying to debug any line, the debugger is not launched and breakpoints are not reachable.

If I capture the output from debug, I got the following:

The program '[11980] WebBrowserTest.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[11980] WebBrowserTest.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

How could I solve this issue.

Comment: in the bin directory are there the pdb ?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any code before initialize() IN main form.  Add break point (F9) just after the initialize() and see if you reach the break point.  If you don't the error is in the design.cs code.  If you reach the break point then continue adding break points to help isolate where the failure is occurring.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi, yes there's a pdb

Comment: what if you try to launch it without debug .. and then attache the debugger to the process?

Comment: @jdweng, it's default application, I didn't add any line of code, I just want the debugger to run correctly.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi, I need to debug some part of the code before the main form is loaded.

Comment: check difference between maybe configuration .. if in debug mode there are some difference from release mode .. or other config

Comment: A default form project will always display a blank for when running in debug mode.  Either you have a break point set, you modified the form with the toolbox, or the form is hiding behind another object.

Comment: @jdweng, default project without adding anything, BTW, the same behaviour in VS 2010, and VS2012.

Comment: I think the error is in the Net library 4.0 (v4.0.30319).   I would make sure you have all the latest security updates install for Net Library.  I would also verify you have Net 4.0 installed by checking the installed applications.  You can also attempt to repair the Net 4.0 Framework.

Comment: @ ManKeer, please use the The .NET Framework setup verification tool https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/10/13/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide/, check your .NET Framework, please also check other simple app with a breakpoint like the C# console or others, if all projects have the same issue, I suggest you repair your VS. Please also install the VS2012 update 5 and VS2010 sp1 for your two VS versions. Of course, to really make sure that it is no the VS issue, just test it in other VS machine will help you narrow down this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution for this issue, it's just related to the windows user privileges, once I run the VS2012 As Administrator, the debugger starts without any problem.